# where clause in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to generate few random links for my wordpress but i don't want to use order by rand as it will cause heavy load on mysql. below links works fine but when i use orderby rand

```
$wprpi_arg = array(
        'numberposts'   => $wprpi_value['post'],
        'post__not_in'  => array(get_the_ID()),
//      'where ID <'   => get_the_ID(),
        'orderby'       => 'rand',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
    );
```

i want to use this instead

```
$wprpi_arg = array(
        'numberposts'   => $wprpi_value['post'],
        'post__not_in'  => array(get_the_ID()),
        'where ID <'   => get_the_ID(),
        'orderby'       => 'ID',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
    );
```

But this is not working. WordPress is listing only 5 last links of table as it is orderby id its showing 5 links in desc order.

But i want to generate 5 links lower than my current id.

For example: if users is on page /10000 the generated links should be 9999,9998,9997,9996,9995 and if user is on /100 page generated links will be 99,98,97,96,95 but wordpress ignores where clause and generates same link always orderby desc limit 5 without considering where clause

Comment: you do not do it like ```where ID <'   => get_the_ID(),``` go for codex .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu can u explain how,i am new to wordpress

Comment: Can you post your full snippet means the query / function your have written here ? if you are having id use it get the post object why you are making a query ?

Comment: You can use `posts_where` filter. see docs at https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where

Comment: @SCC can u give one sample example here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom where condition in your wordpress query as below.

Note: Use get_the_ID() instead of 215 in your case

```
//Add Filter
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'posts_where_for_ID' );
function posts_where_for_ID( $where ) {
    $where .= ' AND ID < '. 215;
    return $where;
}

//Create args
$args = array(
'numberposts'       => 5, //$wprpi_value['post']
'post__not_in'      => array(215),  
'orderby'           => 'ID',
'order'             => 'DESC',
'post_status'       => 'publish',
'suppress_filters'  => FALSE
);

//Get the posts
$desc_posts = get_posts($args);

//Store post ids
$p_ids = array();
foreach($desc_posts as $posts_) {
   $p_ids[] = $posts_->ID;
}

//Your ids are here
var_dump($p_ids);
```

This will applied to all `get_posts()` query in which `suppress_filters` passed in args.

If you have custom post_type then ckeck for post type or if you have single page then add in that page only.